# Context module: User ID / role from url

Tags: 8, blocks

I'm trying to display some blocks on the user profile pages only when the user owing that user profile has certain roles.

I saw there is a node type condition based. Is there a way to do the same for users?

Comment: As alternative for [hook_block_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_access/8.2.x) you can write a Condition Plugin. For example see [article](https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/using-drupal-8-condition-plugins-api) and [example for node based](https://gist.github.com/acrosman/ab7e9ffce3996f6bc1798f9f1ca34c06)

Comment: Not helpful. As I said, I need to do this with the 'context' module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Context "Condition" plugin, and extend the already core existing "UserRole" condition to do this. Here is example code I have tested on 8.7 w/ Context latest dev version. The module is called `ctx_custom`, and this plugin is defined in the file within the module `/src/Plugin/Condition/UserProfileCondition.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\ctx_custom\Plugin\Condition;

use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Drupal\user\Plugin\Condition\UserRole;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\User\Entity\User;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Provides a 'User profile path exclusion' condition.
 *
 * @Condition(
 *   id = "user_profile_condition",
 *   label = @Translation("User profile request exclusion"),
 *   context = {
 *     "user_profile_condition" = @ContextDefinition("user_profile_condition", label = @Translation("User profile path exclusion"))
 *   }
 * )
 */
class UserProfileCondition extends UserRole implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   * @param $plugin_id
   * @param $plugin_definition
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
  }

  /**
   * @param \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container
   * @param array $configuration
   * @param string $plugin_id
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *
   * @return static
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function evaluate() {
    $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
    $params = Url::fromUserInput($current_path)->getRouteParameters();
    if (isset($params['user'])) {
      $configuration = $this->getConfiguration();
      $user = User::load($params['user']);
      foreach ($configuration['roles'] as $role_id) {
        if ($user->hasRole($role_id)) {
          return TRUE;
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Once you've added this plugin definition and enabled the module, you should be able to add this Via `context_ui` as a Condition, and then whatever reaction you want, e.g. showing blocks or any other Context Reaction that is desired.

Answer (score 1):

Since the situation is not very clear as to what block you're placing and how, here are some general suggestions.

If you're using views to display the blocks on the user profile page, you can do the following:

- Add a role condition to the view so that it will only have contents for the correct set of roles
- Enable the option that says *Hide block when empty*
- The block will be empty for all but the right roles; when the block is empty, the block will be hidden

In general, you should be able to implement [`hook_block_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_access/8.2.x) and hide the block based on your requirements.

#### Note

To hide/show a block based on the role of the visiting user, you can simply use the *Roles* condition provided by Drupal Core. But you're case is different because you're trying to hide/show a block based on the user whose profile is being visited.

Comment: I am using the [context module](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) and wanted to be able to restrict the block from context' module admin interface. But I will probably move the logic inside a custom block access function.